# Manga where the main character is summoned to a world he'd been summoned to once before and previously saved

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

From what I remember, the main character is summoned into a fantasy world. However, the twist in this manga is that he was already summoned to this world once before, but after he saved it, the king feared his power, so he forcefully reincarnated the MC back into our world.

In his second life, he was summoned back to the world he was summoned to before. Once he was summoned, he kept his powers a secret, which persisted with him through being reincarnated and the second summoning.

He meets his previous underlings, whom he taught how to fight among other things. Oh by the way, all his underlings are perverts and like to be disciplined by him. They wanted to see their master again, after he was forcefully reincarnated back to his previous world.

Comment: "*Oh by the way all his underlings are perverts*" - aaand there it is...

Comment: lol @Valorum and logicDictates I swear I see you guys everywhere. I think every single on of my posts i see you and while looking up a bunch of manga.

Comment: I watch and read a fair amount of manga and anime. I'd probably hang around on Manga:SE but they're much too knowledgeable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is ***[This Makes My Second Otherworldly Summon](https://myanimelist.net/manga/115310/Isekai_Shoukan_wa_Nidome_desu)***.

From MyAnimeList:

> There was once a man who was summoned to another world, and saved it. Of course, he became too popular there, and turned into an isekai-normie. However, that man fell into a "trap," and was forcibly returned to his original world. Moreover, he had to start over as a baby!
>
> This is the story of the way-too-fantastic ex-hero who lived as a gloomy high schooler as he gets summoned once again to that other world in a very unexpected development!

A class of students is summoned to another world to save the human kingdom there. However, one of the students, Suzaki Setsu, had been summoned to that world once before, and had saved the humans there already.

As you mentioned, the king previously sent Setsu back to his original world, because he feared his power. He wasn't specifically meant to be summoned the second time; he just got brought along with the rest of his class.

Soon after returning to this other world, Setsu reunites with one of his former underlings, who told him she'd missed being spanked by him.

[image]

[image]