# Manga in which the main character just returned from being isekaied and then gets isekaied again with his classmates

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

I can't remember the title of the manga wherein the first chapter, the main character just got back from another world and came to school like nothing happened, then got isekaied again along with his classmates.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. This isn't much to go on though, so if you could provide any more details, they'd come in very hand. For example, was the main character isekaied again the same day that he returned to his world? And can you tell us anything else about the plot or characters?

Answer (score 1):

If you allow for a bit more time after their return from the original summoning, *Isekai Shoukan wa Nidome desu* as per [Manga where the main character is summoned to a world he'd been summoned to once before and previously saved](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/256370/manga-where-the-main-character-is-summoned-to-a-world-hed-been-summoned-to-once)

[image: Cover image of Isekai Shoukan wa Nidome desu]

> There was once a man who was summoned to another world, and saved it. Of course, he became too popular there, and turned into an isekai-normie. However, that man fell into a "trap," and was forcibly returned to his original world. Moreover, he had to start over as a baby!
>
> This is the story of the way-too-fantastic ex-hero who lived as a gloomy high schooler as he gets summoned once again to that other world in a very unexpected development!